# Duplicate HTTP Request files are creating in my JMeter result

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-404, http-response-codes

Facing issues in my Jmeter results and few of them are listed below,

**1.** Multiple HTTP requests are creating for a single request, Where initial request is getting passed and rest of the duplicate requests are getting **404 error**. Please check with below shown image for reference

[image]

**2.** Also in JMeter user.properties file below mentioned line is added,

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

[image]

But still the result is getting failed as like mentioned in the ***1st issue***. Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove 1st `#` symbol as it indicates [line comment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)) therefore JMeter doesn't consider this line.

1. Make sure that the line is not in green
2. JMeter restart will be required to pick the property change up

Another option is [passing the property via `-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

```
jmeter -Jhttpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) article to learn more about JMeter properties and ways of setting/overriding them

---

However I would rather recommend raising a product issue as [HTTP 404 status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) [are not very good for SEO](https://www.custard.co.uk/404-errors)